# Como pedir um número em python porém limitarlo a 2 casas decimais?

Tags: python, formatação, decimal

Sei fazer o resultado aparecer com 2 casas decimais usando o:

```
numeroFloat=int(input(''))

print('{:.2f}'.format(numeroFloat))
```

porém quero que a variavel numeroFlat seja guardada apenas com 2 casas decimais.

Exemplo:

```
numeroFloat=int(input(''))

print(numeroFloat)
```

Quero que o print seja exibido com 2 casas decimais no print acima.

Answer (score -1):

Olá.
Se você vai receber esses dados via banco de dados ou api por exemplo, seria mais fácil tratar da origem.
Se vai receber do usuário, pode colocar um placeholder informando a quantidade de caracteres aceitos.
Mas acredito que não tenha como limitar no input.
O que você pode fazer é criar uma condição
ex:

```
if 0 <= num <= 100:
//do something
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Opa amigo, tente fazer o seguinte:

```
numeroFloat=float(input(''))

meu_formato = "{0:.2f}"

numeroFloatDecimalFixado = meu_formato.format(numeroFloat)

print(numeroFloatDecimalFixado)
```

Referência: [Link](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-format-a-floating-number-in-python)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: não expliquei bem, é o programa pedir um número float, e eu dar exemplo o número 15.6754, porém ele salvar essa variavel só com maximo 2 casas decimas ou seja ele salvar 15.67.
Sem eu ter a necessidade de a cada print desse numero ter q por o '{:.2f}'.format(numero) para que apareça 15.67